# Laravel protect anonymous user accessing register form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in my application, i am consuming default laravel register form. i want to prevent anonymous users from accessing the signup form.

**Current Output:-**  register form is not protected, so authenticated and anonymous users can both access register form

**Expected output:-** Only authenticated users can access this register form.

Answer (score 0):

you can use auth middleware in your auth controller for register method
like -

```
// in auth controller
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['getRegister']]);
    }

}
```

or you can use route middleware

```
// in route.php
Route::get('register', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@getRegister'
]);
```

Comment: i just copied your Route  snippet in the route.php but not working,            Having one quick questions:  1. i don't have function called getRegister, let me know i have write anywhere or inside authController ?

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5.0 in built Registrar trait and It's AuthController then, getRegister method must be there in the AuthController. If not then whatever controller you are using, just add the auth middleware into that Controller's construct method, or you can add the middleware directly into the route, as in the answer's second example

Comment: not working. ]);
Route::get('auth\register', [
    'middleware' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@getRegister'
]);

Comment: system still not performing authentication well